# Integer.parseInt error

Tags: java

I just began Java. I am trying to compile this program

```
class poop{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("1"));
  }
}
```

But I get this error

```
poop.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("1"));
                          ^
  symbol:   method parseInt(String)
  location: class Integer
./Integer.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
Int a=5;
^
  symbol:   class Int
  location: class Integer
2 errors
```

What's up?

I'm using JDK 7 on Lubuntu

Comment: Is that the *entire* class listing?

Comment: @Bohemian: Nope.  The OP left out "public class Integer {}" ... which would have led directly to the cause of the problem ;)

Comment: Nope, he named his class poop but his file Integer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have named your java file `Integer`, but

1. That doesn't match the class name inside the file (`poop`), and
2. It shadows `java.lang.Integer`.

Name the file the same thing as the top-level class it contains, and *definitely not* `Integer`.

Comment: Err, I was doing javac poop.java, but I removed the Integer.java/.class files and it worked. Strange. OK. Thank you. :) Edit: OH I UNDERSTAND because I made those classes, got it

Comment: +1 for answer, but also for losing the Cyrillic characters from your user name

Comment: @Bohemian that was years ago!